# MPlayer — changing brightness/ contrast to video file and save output

Tags: linux, multimedia, brightness, mplayer, contrast

I need to change brightness and contrast to a video permanently, I tried this:

```
mplayer -vf eq=50:50 a.mp4 -dumpstream
mv stream.dump b.mp4
```

But it saves as a file which look likes the original file. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use mencoder to transcode the video to apply the video filter `eq=50:50`. When you use `-dumpstream` with mplayer, it simply dumps the stream while the video filter is being applied to playback. Take a look at the mencoder options, but you'll need to chose a video codec and some options for that codec (like bitrate). Then you can apply the brightness and contrast filter.

Comment: with the command: `mencoder a.mp4 -oac copy -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=8000 -vf eq=75:100 -force-avi-aspect 1.777 -o b.mp4` i get the video but the video bitrate doesn't match with the vbitrate... grgrgrg i tried with bits, bytes, kbytes, always puts: Video stream:  602.555 kbit/s WTF